# What's the difference between failparentonfailure and propagate in SSIS

Tags: ssis

What's the difference between  failparentonfailure property and propagate variable of event handler in SSIS?
What's the difference between error event handler and task failure event handler in SSIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FailParentOnfailure is for failing a parent container despite of setting the MaxErrorCount on the parent container (for loop, foreach loop, etc.). The Propagate solution is for preventing event propagation to the parent. See http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2014/05/continue-loop-after-error.html

Comment: IF I set FailParentOnfailure true and set variable propagate false,when the task fails,will the parent container fail?